# Tables with images in HTML

Tags: html, email

I am attempting to use HTML to create an email? I don't really know much about this to begin with so I'm working from no previous knowledge as its my first time. Do I need to host the images on a website if I am going to reference them in the email? Or can I just directly reference the location on my computer?

Comment: What will you use to send the e-mail? That makes the difference on where do you keep the images.

Comment: Think of it this way. Call a buddy who lives across town and tell him or her to look up in the sky to see the moon. That's a URL pointing to a server somewhere. Now tell them to check out what's on your tv. That's a link to the file on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two important thing you have to know about HTML e-mails:

- You can use a table just fine to organize the content, and
- You have to use inline CSS to style the non-image parts.

[Here](http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/html-email-basics/) is a very nice but short guide you can use as a checklist for your first prototype. [Here is another, multi-part tutorial.](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/series/mastering-html-email--webdesign-17696) [Here's a third one.](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-simple-responsive-html-email--webdesign-12978) And you can find a lot more on Google.

For images, you probably have to store them on a private server or an image hosting service - if you have no access to a server, [imgur](http://imgur.com/) can possibly work, too.

Answer (score 0):

images needs to be hosted somewhere and accessible via the network (with absolutes url and not relatives urls)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Image should be included. the following link might help. http://moz.com/community/q/where-to-host-images-for-e-mail-newsletter

Answer (score 0):

You most definitely cannot reference them from your computer.

You can either reference them with full URLs, as in:

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/directory/image.gif" />
```

Or you can attach them to the email as files and reference them with the name of the attached file:

```
<img src="attached_image.gif" />
```

Some mail clients will reject either method for security reasons (it can be considered a security breach to either automatically download an attachment or to retrieve an external URL, especially from webmail clients in the latter case).  This is why you see links like "Having problems viewing this email?  Click here to view it online" or email clients with the option to download images that are not displayed by default.